# Custom Indentation

Tags: indentation, eledmac

I am using the eledmac package to compose a document that will have verse interspersed with prose.  Because of the way eledmac functions, I can't use the "verse" environment and have it come out correctly if I want eledmac to number the text.  The reason is that eledmac doesn't recognize environments within text it is meant to number.  So, I have to format the verses manually. The verse has to be more indented than a normal paragraph indentation.  So, my question is: is there a command similar to \indent that will indent the text but with an option for how much you want to indent it? I was expecting that the \indent command should have some kind of option such that one could, for example, input \indent[3cm] to make a 3 cm indent, but no such luck.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you can simply use `\hspace{3cm}`, but if you put the information you gave with so many words into a minimal working example (i.e. code), somebody may come up with a better solution.

Comment: you can put this before the first line of a paragraph of the verse: `\noindent\hangindent 3cm \hspace*{3cm}%` and then end every line with `\\ `.

Comment: How to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `stanza` tools of eledmac. See this MWE

```
\beginnumbering
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}
\setstanzaindents{8,0,1}
\stanza
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,&
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore&
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud&
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi&
\edtext{ut aliquip}{\Afootnote{ut aliliquip}} consequat ut aliquip consequat irure dolor in reprehenderit irure dolor in reprehenderit&
\edtext{Duis aute}{\Bfootnote{Some comments}} irure dolor in reprehenderit&
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu ur. Excepteur sint occaecat&
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt&
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit&
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla&
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat\&
\endnumbering
```

and also the handbook

Comment: Thank you for this, I should have seen this in the eledmac manual before.  I searched for "verse" in the manual and didn't find anything so I assumed there was nothing like this; I didn't think to search for "stanza."  Out of curiosity -- in the standard "verse" environment there is whitespace included before and after the text in verse.  The eledmac '\stanza' command doesn't provide this; I have been doing it manually with '\vspace' instead.  Do you know if there is an option for this in eledmac?

Comment: The section 5 of the handbook has the title "verse". You can define a `\startstanzahook` command to add your `\vspace`.

Comment: please validate the answer if ok

Comment: Oh, then I don't know how I missed the "Verse" section in the manual!  In any case, the `\startstanzahook` command does work for adding space before the verse, but it doesn't do anything at the end of the section of verse in `\stanza` mode.

Comment: use the ` \newverse`. § 5.7 and example `text-between-verses-in-parallel.tex`

Comment: I compiled the file you mentioned but the monitor says that `\newverse` is an "undefined control sequence."  I couldn't find mention of it in the eledmac manual.  Which document are you referring to when you cite § 5.7?

Comment: I think you have not the last version of eledmac (v1.14.0)

Comment: I was reffering to the handbook.

Comment: But I made a mistake, you should look at the optional argument of `\&`

Comment: Yes, indeed my version of eledmac is old.  It doesn't include the `\newverse` command, nor does it say anything about including optional arguments with `\&`, which the new handbook does.  I will try it again once I get the newer version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18962/discussion-between-paul-and-maieul).